# ORM Relationships, PHP and SQL Join

Tags: php, sql, orm

I'm working on a little PHP Framework for a school project and I'm currently learning how to build the ORM part.

However, I can't figure out how to map object relationships from a SQL query with joins or I just don't know the right words to search :(

```
t1
  id
  title
  text
```

-

```
t2
  id
  name
  description
```

I tried to do a simple : SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id

What I get is a simple array with all the fields from both tables and id column gets overridden as It exist in both.

```
[
  "id" => "2"
  "title" => "Lorem"
  "text" => "Ipsum"
  "name" => "Tomato"
  "description" => "Tomato are nice"
]
```

So my question is there a simple way to get something like this with joins ?

```
[
  "t1" => [
     "id" => 2
     "title" => "Lorem"
     "text" => "Tomato"
     "t2" => [
       "id" => 3
       "name" => "Tomato"
       "description" => "Tomato are nice"
     ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a join is for creating a table view of the two tables side to side. But you can do:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t1.next, t2.name as "t2_name", t2.description as "t2_description" FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

Which will give you prefixes like:

```
[
    "t1" => [
        "id" => 2
        "title" => "Lorem"
        "text" => "Tomato"
        "id" => 3
        "t2_name" => "Tomato"
        "t2_description" => "Tomato are nice"
    ]
]
```

That solves the same problem you were trying to solve.